# view data from database not working using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a code for viewing all the data from my database and the code is working fine without the `WHERE` in sql statement but when I try to manipulate the sql and put a `WHERE` clause in not working anymore it gives me a "0" value when i echoed it..

**here is my code**

**user.php**

```
public function province($query)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo "<td>" .$result['id']." </td>";
        echo "<td>" .$result['area']. "</td>";
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
     $query="SELECT COUNT(Province) AS id, FORMAT((SUM(Area)),0) AS area FROM rlbet WHERE Province='ALBAY' AND Year_Approved='2014'";
     $LTID->province($query);
?>

<?php
     $query="SELECT COUNT(Province) AS id, FORMAT((SUM(Area)),0) AS area FROM rlbet WHERE Province='CAMARINES NORTE' AND Year_Approved='2014'";
                    $LTID->province($query);
?>
```

**below is the original code**
**original code which is working**

```
public function province()
{
$stmt = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(ID) AS id, FORMAT((SUM(ID)),0) AS total from rlbet");

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo "<td>" .$result['id']." </td>";
    echo "<td>" .$result['area']. "</td>";
}
```

**index.php**
**original code**

```
<?php
     echo $LTID->province();
?>
```

**error**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FORMAT((SUM(Area)),0) AS area FROM rlbet WHERE Province='CAMARINES NORTE' AND Ye' at line 1' in D:\wamp\www\LTID\class.user.php on line 130
```

Comment: Are there any records matched `Province='ALBAY' AND Year_Approve='2014'` or `Province='CAMARINES NORTE' AND Year_Approve='2014'`?

Comment: @Reno yes. they're all stored in the database.

Comment: your query result does not contain `id` and `total`.:(

Comment: yeah i'm sorry for that i already updated my code but the still the problem occur

Comment: Which column is 0?

Comment: all of it..let me update my code above and show you my original code where it works first.

Comment: i already updated my code above

Comment: Would you please execute the sql include `where` in the mysql console check if there is error or not?

Comment: i already tried that and it working but i don't know why its not working inside the php..anf i now get an erro..

Comment: You never `->execute()` the prepared statement!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function province($province, $year_approved)
{
$stmt = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(ID) AS id, FORMAT((SUM(ID)),0) AS total from rlbet WHERE Province=:Province AND Year_Approved=:YearApproved");
$stmt->bindValue(':Province', $province, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':YearApproved', $year_approved, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<td>" .$result['id']." </td>";
echo "<td>" .$result['area']. "</td>";
}


<?php
province('ALBAY', '2014');
province('CAMARINES NORTE', '2014');    
?>
```

Comment: i try it but i get this error  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FORMAT((SUM(Area)),0) AS area FROM rlbet WHERE Province='CAMARINES NORTE' AND Ye' at line 1' in D:\wamp\www\LTID\class.user.php on line 130

Comment: but what if i echo it in the other page?

Comment: as long as you can call the function, you can echo it in other page.

Comment: why do you have this code?  <?php
province('ALBAY', '2014');
province('CAMARINES NORTE', '2014');    
?>

Comment: because the function `province()` is already returning an echo, that's why you don't have to do this: `echo province('ALBAY', '2014');`